# magento administrator is not running in ubuntu lamp localhost

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides

I have just shifted my magento site to ubuntu root from windows xamp. Now some urls like 
`http://localhost/magento/admin` and `http://localhost/magento/phones` display errors:

```
The requested URL /magento/admin was not found on this server.
```

I think mod_rewrite is not working so I did the instructions in this post:

https://askubuntu.com/a/48363/198032

but still I am receiving the same error:

Comment: Don't use `localhost` as host name. Use `127.0.0.1` or a virtual host.

Comment: As Marius said, do not use localhost, you can find the way for configuration here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10324/231

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question will have an answer.
It seams that magento doesn't work with the base url `http://localhost/...`.
It needs a domain name that has a dot (`.`) in it.
Instead of `localhost` you can use `127.0.0.1` or create a virtual host like `magento.local` just as @AnnaVölkl [describes here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10324/146)